# В class="block" не отображается border и background-color, а в class="block_all" отображаются

Tags: html, css

html

```
<aside>
      <div class="block_all">
         <div class="block_1" class="block">xrfygjnfgcjc</div>
         <div class="block_2" class="block">dfhdfxhxd</div>
         <div class="block_3" class="block">xdfhdhdh</div>
      </div>
    </aside>
```

css

```
.block_all{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    height: 150px;
}
.block{
    background-color: #ff99a5;
    border: 2px solid silver;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 класса сразу для блока ты задал неверно, нужно сделать так

```
<aside>
      <div class="block_all">
         <div class="block_1 block">xrfygjnfgcjc</div>
         <div class="block_2 block">dfhdfxhxd</div>
         <div class="block_3 block">xdfhdhdh</div>
      </div>
 </aside>
```